# how to write tests to ensure that a conversion from Markdown to HTML works well in Java

Tags: java, android, markdown

I have been working on this issue for days. The codes below are in my TextUtils.java class

protected static String markdownToHtml(String text) {

```
    text = text.replaceAll("<([^a-zA-Z/])", "&lt;$1");
    // https://github.com/enketo/enketo-transformer/blob/master/src/markdown.js

    // span - replaced &lt; and &gt; with <>
    text = ReplaceCallback.replace("(?s)<\\s?span([^\\/\n]*)>((?:(?!<\\/).)+)<\\/\\s?span\\s?>",
            text, createSpan);
    // strong
    text = text.replaceAll("/__(.*?)__/gm", "<strong>$1</strong>");
    text = text.replaceAll("/\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*/gm", "<strong>$1</strong>");
    // emphasis
    text = text.replaceAll("/_([^\\s][^_\\n]*)_/gm", "<em>$1</em>");
    text = text.replaceAll("/\\*([^\\s][^*\\n]*)\\*/gm", "<em>$1</em>");
    // links
    text = text.replaceAll("/\\[([^\\\\]]*)\\\\]\\(([^)]+)\\)/gm",
            "<a href=\"$2\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
    // headers - requires ^ or breaks <font color="#f58a1f">color</font>
    text = ReplaceCallback.replace("(?s)^(#+)([^\n]*)$", text, createHeader);
    // paragraphs
    text = ReplaceCallback.replace("(?s)([^\n]+)\n", text, createParagraph);

    // "\" will be used as escape character for *, _
    text = text
            .replaceAll("/\\\\/gm", "'&92;'")
            .replaceAll(" /\\\\\\*gm", "'&42;'")
            .replaceAll(" /\\\\_/gm", "'&95;'")
            .replaceAll(" /\\\\#/gm", "'&35;'");
    return text;
}
```

and these are the tests Ive been trying to run

```
@Test
    public void markDownToHtmlEscapesBackslash() {
        String[][] tests = {
                { "A\\_B\\_C", "A_B_C"},
                { "_A\\_B\\_C_", "<em>A_B_C</em>"},
                { "A_B\\_C", "A_B_C"},
                { "A\\_B_C", "A_B_C"},
                { "A_B_C", "A<em>B</em>C"},
                { "\\__AB\\__", "_<em>AB_</em>"},
                { "\\\\_AB\\_\\\\_", "\\<em>AB_\\</em>"},
                { "A\\*B\\*C", "A*B*C"},
                { "*A\\*B\\*C*", "<em>A*B*C</em>"},
                { "A*B\\*C", "A*B*C"},
                { "A*B*C", "A<em>B</em>C"},
                { "\\**AB\\**", "*<em>AB*</em>"},
                { "\\\\*AB\\*\\\\*", "\\<em>AB*\\</em>"},
                { "\\a\\ b\\*c\\d\\_e", "\\a\\ b*c\\d_e"},
                { "\\#1", "#1"},
                { "\\#\\# 2", "## 2"},
                { "works \\#when not required too", "works #when not required too"},
                { "\\", "\\"},
                { "\\\\", "\\"},
                { "\\\\\\", "\\\\"}
        };
        for (String[] testCase: tests) {
            Assert.assertEquals(testCase[1], TextUtils.markdownToHtml(testCase[0]));
        }
    }
```

and it produces this errors

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :A_B_C
Actual   :A_B_C
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51276', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1

Please how can i fix this?

Comment: I think you have white character somewhere\

Comment: Why not use [an actual Markdown to HTML library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/60?sort=created)?

Comment: The question in your title and the question at the bottom are not anything like the same.  Please pick one question, and stick to it (but not before visiting the [help] to make it on topic).

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for your answer. can you please identify where this white character is?

Comment: @CommonsWare I cant do that because its an open source project I am contributing to and this is the format they want to work with.

Comment: Why not ask the developers of the open source project why they are not using an actual Markdown to HTML library?

Comment: hello @CommonsWare I want to use the actual Markdown to HTML library please how can I go about it?

Comment: I linked to [the Android Arsenal's Markdown category](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/60?sort=created) in my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563241/how-to-write-tests-to-ensure-that-a-conversion-from-markdown-to-html-works-well?noredirect=1#comment86134671_49563241). I maintain [one Markdown to HTML library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown), but there are others.